# How would I send health data from a Samsung watch to our web service using an API?

Tags: android, rest, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy-gear

The company I work for has a health-based web service that allows users to enter clinical results and other health information for tracking purposes, and we would like to get data from a user's Samsung watch and send it to our website via an API. From my understanding, I need to develop an application in Android that reads the data and sends it to our website with a POST. There is a vaguely similar post to this one, but it has no answers, and I could not upvote because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: im not sure if this on-topic but what exactly are you asking for ?

Comment: let me rephrase are you looking for a developer ? or do you want one to do it for you ? or you are a developer and you don't know where to begin ? because in the case num1 and num2  you might need to post a job. case num3 you might need to tell more of what you really want?

Comment: I need a general outline of what to do. Not sure what is confusing about that. The answer below helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search    'Apache MQTT '  for more infomation.